# sdb1 keeps showing unknown partition after every restart

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

My external hard drive has two partitions. `sdb1` keeps missing after shutting down the laptop and turn on again. But If I restart after formatting the drive, the drives work fine. But once I shut down and turn on again, the drive is missing. I tried to format and re-partitioned it few times. The problem is occurring since I converted the drive from `fat32` to `ext4`. `sdb2` works fine though.

I'm a beginner. I have a backup of that drive but I want it to be fixed. Please help me.

UPDATE : I made 3 partitions now. `sdb1` still does not work. `sdb2 & sdb3` is still working file. So I deleted `sdb1` and kept it unallocated because if I keep it, the bootload is very slow. Maybe 2 mins. This is not a solution so I'd really appreciate if somebody can help me. Thanks

Here is what Gnome Gparted showing.

> ```
> e2label: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdb1
> Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
>
> tune2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
>
> tune2fs: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdb1
> Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
>
> Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
>
> dumpe2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
> dumpe2fs: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdb1
>
> Unable to read the contents of this file system!
> Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
> The cause might be a missing software package.
> The following list of software packages is required for ext4 file system support:  e2fsprogs v1.41+.
> ```

sudo blkid

```
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="DEVPOINT"
UUID="27fef8c5-4bf0-4af2-b974-095943ef1a97" TYPE="ext4"
PARTUUID="dae1d3d3-72c5-41b3-a9a9-b2e323af02ff" /dev/sda1:
UUID="385D-275B" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0000a47d-01"
```

sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 047BA8A3-3425-48BC-8983-62CFCDD18ADB

Device         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048  996300799 996298752 475.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb2  996300800 1953523711 957222912 456.5G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sda: 223.58 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: Corsair Force LE
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0000a47d

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1953791   1951744   953M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda2       1955838 468860927 466905090 222.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1955840 468860927 466905088 222.7G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Try recreating sdb1 now using gparted. If issues continue, then I suspect a hardware problem. I am troubled by the message "The following list of software packages is required for ext4 file system support:  e2fsprogs v1.41+.": what is your specific Ubuntu version?

Comment: Thank your brother! I tried to re-create the partition and now it is working very fine. No problem whatsoever!! 

My Ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS version. I have "Disk is ok, 200 bad sectors" message showing in Disks. Does it mean my disk will be damaged very soon?!

Comment: Today morning, The problem is still occuring. I don't know what's the problem. Only sdb1 gets vanished.

Comment: Time for a new drive, I guess.